# Receiving error when I run console app from SSIS package but not in debug

Tags: c#, selenium, ssis

I have written a package that uses Selenium to navigate to a website and download a CSV. I have a master package that runs multiple child packages to run this web scraper simultaneously for different parameters, and the child packages in turn loop through another set of parameters and download two different formats of CSV. Here is my control flow:

1. Master SSIS package calls multiple instances of Child Package:
2. Each child package logs the start time to a db.
3. The child package calls a c# console app (runs in hidden mode).
4. The c# app navigates to the website; enters parameters; downloads the CSV; manipulates the text; and moves/renames the CSV to a results folder.
5. The package logs the end time with any error that occurred, and then repeats 2, 3 & 4 on a different website that returns a differently formatted CSV. The same console app is used for both runs.
6. The package logs the end time for the second run, along with any error.
7. The package loops and runs through the same process for a different set of parameters.

I took this project over from someone else. These website calls can take a very long time, and sometimes time out altogether. To handle this, my child package doesn't fail the console app on error -- it just has an SSIS error handler to pick up the error text via a small VSTA app and it continues, while logging the error to the db.

Every single time the console app runs from this configuration, it returns this error:

```
[32.676][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 9.993
[32.689][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.013
```

The seconds are variable, the text is not.

As far as I can tell, this is not an actual error -- the file has successfully downloaded and moved with all records. But if I run the console app on its own, or in debug mode, I don't see this error. I can't tell where it's coming from: Selenium, a problem with the handoff from the console back to SSIS, if there's a problem with the visibility of the console app, if I should just ignore this error when it occurs... any ideas?

Comment: Does the console app return an int when it finishes or fails? Running the app from say PowerShell does it receive the int and / or return to the prompt?

Comment: aHA, ok. So this is a timeout error on one of the intermediate website hits to enter credentials. This error is handled in a local try/catch, and the code continues successfully. But for some reason, this error text is still getting stored in my SSIS Console app property StandardErrorVariable. The return code of the console app is zero. How would I prevent this passage back from the Console app?